# Spurious regression and autocorrelation?

Tags: stationarity, beta-distribution, augmented-dickey-fuller

I have calculated portfolio returns, using a zero cost strategy. I  have data with monthly returns, that I try to explain with the Capital Asset Pricing Model (CAPM). That is, my dependent variable is portfolio returns at time t, and independent variable is the return on OSEAX (Oslo Stock Index). The returns from the portfolio are all calculated with log. The same is true for the index. That is, for the index, each month I have a return of ln(P_t / P_t-1) from the index, wheree P_t is the price at time t. 
My problem is that the beta in both the winner, loser and zero-cost portfolio is very significant. See picture:

[image: Regression output]

This raised question of spurious regression. All my data are in log returns as said. The plots for each data look stationary, and when I run the Augmented Dickey Fueller Test, I can reject the H0 for no unit root for all variables.

Any tips?

Also, I have a question 2: I do not understand the connection with the autocorrelation function and stationarity. See picture. My data (log returns) has significant spikes, which in my mind is "bad". Looking at the plot and ADF test it looks stationary. Can a series be autocorrelated and still be stationary?

[image]

Comment: Please roll back any of my edits that missed the mark.

Comment: Isn't stationarity always assessed on a much longer time-scale than autocorrelation?  E.g., over 200 observations instead of at lags of about 1-30.  Thus I think a series can have one without the other, or both, or neither.

Comment: I see that *spurious regression* has a meaning specific to time-series analysis.  https://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/examples/time-series-regression-iv-spurious-regression.html#d119e2943